# SUM distinct inside window function

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, distinct, window-functions

I have a data structure similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
    dude_id INTEGER, 
    main_date TIMESTAMP, 
    how_many INTEGER, 
    how_much NUMERIC(5,2), 
    their_ids INTEGER[]
)
```

This is the query I've got so far

```
SELECT
    dude_id,
    main_date,
    how_many,
    how_much,
    their_ids,
    SUM(how_many) OVER (PARTITION BY dude_id ORDER BY main_date) AS count_stuff_WRONG,
    SUM(how_much) OVER (PARTITION BY dude_id ORDER BY main_date) AS cumulative_sum_WRONG
FROM some_table
```

This is the result I'm trying to achieve:

| dude_id | main_date | how_many | how_much | their_ids | count_stuff_EXPECTED | cumulative_sum_EXPECTED | count_stuff_WRONG | cumulative_sum_WRONG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 38 | 2019-06-14 | 1 | 6 | 373 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 6 |
| 38 | 2019-07-15 | 1 | 7 | 374 | 2 | 13 (6+7) | 2 | 13 (6+7) |
| 38 | 2019-07-16 | 1 | 8 | 375 | 3 | 21 (6+7+8) | 3 | 21 (6+7+8) |
| 38 | 2020-06-14 | 1 | 16 | 373 | 3 | 31 (7+8+16) | 4 | 37 (6+7+8+16) |
| 38 | 2020-07-15 | 1 | 17 | 374 | 3 | 41 (8+16+17) | 5 | 54 (6+7+8+16+17) |
| 38 | 2020-07-16 | 1 | 18 | 375 | 3 | 51 (16+17+18) | 6 | 72 (6+7+8+16+17+18) |

Columns `count_stuff_EXPECTED` and `cumulative_sum_EXPECTED` are what I'm trying to get, columns `count_stuff_WRONG` and `cumulative_sum_WRONG` are the ones my current query is returning.

In other words, I want to get cumulative values for each main_date but without counting/summing multiple times the same `their_ids`. So on row 4, for example, the window partition has `their_ids {373}` more than once, so it should be considered only the most recent one (row 4) and not consider the first occurrence (row 1)

NOTE: there's no need to show on the query how the sum was calculated, I just put it in there in parentheses for clarity.

I tried using

```
SUM(DISTINCT how_many) over (PARTITION BY dude_id ORDER BY main_date) as count_stuff
```

but got

> ERROR:  DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/44850/2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the best answer, but I think it get your goal.

First I make an `INNER JOIN` of table data with itself to get witch values will be sum for each row (newer record for each their_ids). Then I `GROUP BY` to discard "duplicated" rows, I finally I get the sum.

```
WITH sq1 AS (SELECT d1.dude_id, d1.main_date, d1.how_many, d1.how_much, d1.their_ids,
                    d2.dude_id AS d2_dude_id, d2.main_date AS d2_main_date, d2.their_ids AS d2_their_ids,
                   FIRST_VALUE(d2.how_much) OVER (PARTITION BY d1.dude_id, d1.main_date, d1.their_ids, d2.their_ids ORDER BY d2.main_date DESC) AS how_much_to_sum
             FROM data d1
             INNER JOIN data d2 ON d1.dude_id = d2.dude_id AND d1.main_date >= d2.main_date),
            
     sq2 AS (SELECT dude_id, main_date, how_many, how_much, their_ids, d2_dude_id, d2_their_ids, MIN(how_much_to_sum) AS how_much_to_sum
             FROM sq1
             GROUP BY dude_id, main_date, how_many, how_much, their_ids, d2_dude_id, d2_their_ids)
             
select
      dude_id,
      main_date,
      how_many,
      how_much,
      their_ids,
      SUM(how_many) AS count_stuff,
      SUM(how_much_to_sum) AS cumulative_sum
      
from sq2
GROUP BY dude_id, main_date, how_many, how_much, their_ids
ORDER BY main_date;
```